# fail to redefine "java.io.ObjectInputStream" with ByteBuddy?

Tags: byte-buddy

Fail to redefine java.io.ObjectInputStream with ByteBuddy.

I have tried many ways to solve this problem. But I can not find methods to hook "java.io.ObjectInputStream$resolveClass".May you help me?

```java
new AgentBuilder.Default()
//                .ignore(none())
                .type(named("java.io.ObjectInputStream"))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader,module) ->
                        builder.method(named("resolveClass"))
                                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(TimerAdvice.class)))
                .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.REDEFINITION)
                .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
                .installOn(inst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MethodDelegation would invoke a suitable method in TimerAdvice. For this to be possible that class would need to be loaded on the bootstrap class loader. Is this the case in your scenario?

Alternatively, look into using Advice for decorating a method.

Comment: i have add the agent jar to bootstrap loader by :   
instrument.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(new JarFile("my agent jar path"));
But it throws exception at runtime :   
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception